# Drawing on Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have a Bitmap and I want to draw circle or square on it. 
Do I need to use canvas or there is possibility to draw on Bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `Canvas` to draw data into a `Bitmap` instance, simply by creating a `Canvas` instance and passing the `Bitmap` to the constructor.  **However**, the `Bitmap` must be **mutable** or you will not be able to edit its pixel data.  By default, any `Bitmap` created by loading an image file, etc. is **immutable**.  You will likely need to use one of the versions of `Bitmap.createBitmap()` that takes the original as a parameter in order to make a mutable copy you can draw on top of.

Answer (score 1):

Create Canvas on existing Bitmap and you can draw.

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw on canvas like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

canvas.drawText("Test", 100, 100);
```